# Addition multiple array of extra attributes in eloquent many-to-many insertion gives me error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I am new to Laravel framework. To be exact, I'm using Laravel 5.6 now. Recently I have some problem with insertion of many-to-many relation with an array of extra attributes.

Here is my script:

```
$data = [
      "produk_id" => [
        0 => 17,
        1 => 7,
        2 => 2,
      ],
      "tarif" => [
        29290,
        119395,
        89873,
      ],
      "qty" => [
        0 => 4,
        1 => 6,
        2 => 13,
      ],
    ];

Transaksi::find(1)->produk()->attach($data['produk_id'], ['tarif'=>$data['tarif']]);
```

It gives me this error:

[image: got some exception, but... the query seems to be true. hmmm...]

It is strange that the query produced seems to be true. But warn by some exception.

So, i then change the strategy to map the tarif array that suit to the [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) like this:

```
$data_tarif = array_map(function ($item) {
        return ['tarif' => $item];
    }, $data['tarif']);
```

And then pass it to second parameter of attach as extra attributes:

```
Transaksi::find(1)->produk()->attach($data['produk_id'], $data_tarif);
```

But it still gives me an exception, even so far from my expectation:

[image: So far from expectation query]

Am I wrong to use that attach method with multiple arrays of an extra attribute? Since I've tried with a simple array or Laravel documentation, but they seem not work well. what should I do to fix them?

Some attachment to help:
This is my Transaksi model and Produk model

```
class Transaksi extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'transaksi';

   public function user()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');

   public function customer()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
   }

   public function produk()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Produk::class, 'detail_transaksi');
   }
}


class Produk extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'produk';

  public function transaksi() 
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Transaksi::class, 'detail_transaksi');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$attachArray = array();
foreach ($data['produk_id'] as $index => $id) {
    $attachArray[$id] = ['tarif' => $data['tarif'][$index]];
}
Transaksi::find(1)->produk()->attach($attachArray);
```

Comment: try my answer and give me response.